# Google App Engine automatic scaling not keeping instance alive

Tags: google-app-engine

I am struggling to understand the scaling for my NodeJS app running on Google App Engine (Standard). I'm trying to use automatic_scaling but would always like to have 1 instance ready to serve. Reading through all docs this should be easily possible by using the min_instances property as below. I have tried the blow with F1 and F2 instances.

```
runtime: nodejs10
instance_class: F2
automatic_scaling:
  min_instances: 1
  max_instances: 10
  min_idle_instances: 1
  max_concurrent_requests: 70
  target_throughput_utilization: 0.8
```

I can still monitor my instances going down to 0 instances though. The first request then takes a few seconds until the instance is back up and running. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Does your `app.yaml` contains [`automatic_scaling`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#scaling_elements) element? and Have you enabled warmup requests? you must enable [warmup request](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/configuring-warmup-requests#enabling_warmup_requests) to reduce request and response latency during the time when your app's code is being loaded to a newly created instance.

Comment: Any luck fixing this?